# Codeigniter Where generate wrong query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, where-clause

I try to get all cities of country but the codeigniter generate wrong sql, Why?
Here is my Model

```
private $cities    = "cities";

public function get_cities_by_country($country_id){
    $this->db->select('id, city');
    $this->db->where('country_id', $country_id);
    $this->db->from($this->cities);
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

And I use a log_message for $country_id And $this->db->last_query()

```
INFO  - 2017-01-16 18:30:25 --> '7'
INFO  - 2017-01-16 18:30:25 --> 'SELECT `id`, `city`
FROM (`cities`)
WHERE `country_id` =  \'7\'
AND `status` =  1'
```

I think this is a probliem  `country_id` =  \'7\'
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CI is attempting to escape the where value, you can avoid it by passing FALSE as an optional parameter to your where clause:

```
    $this->db->where('country_id', $country_id, FALSE);
```

Read more here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html